# Adverb EVER to make the sentence clearer?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

I have just read this article:

http://literalminded.wordpress.com/2014/07/08/open-conditionals-with-the-past-perfect/

I admit that it is quite tricky for an ESL as I am, nonetheless I caught sight of this sentence:

> But the plane dispatched to the position of another smaller blip found nothing. If there **had been** a lifeboat, it **had sunk**.

I was wondering whether the adverb **ever** could have made the meaning of the sentence above clearer:

> But the plane dispatched to the position of another smaller blip found nothing. If there **had EVER been** a lifeboat, it **had sunk**.

Comment: For me, *Ever* will make it ambiguous. Clearly the time duration is from noticing a blip to plane reaching there. I would rather use **Even** in the beginning of 2nd sentence if emphasis is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "ever" here is redundant.
It is technically OK, but since the described event had a relative start and end time in the past, you don't need it.

*Ever* is more often used to refer to any/all time, as in:

> Have you **ever** gone to New York?
>   They lived happily **ever** after.